# Java String finder - How can I toggle case sensitivity?

Tags: java, case-sensitive

I have a method that searches a file for the strings you give it and returns a count. However I am having trouble with case sensitivity. Here is the method:

```
public int[] count(String[] searchFor, String fileName) {
    int[] counts = new int[searchFor.length];
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < searchFor.length; i++) {
            if (strLine.contains(searchFor[i])) {
                counts[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return counts;
}
```

I parse it an array of Strings to search for in the file. However some of the Strings in the array need to be searched for ignoring case. How can I change my method to accomodate this as am completely stumped.

This method is used by multiple classes so I can't simply insert an if statement into the for loop that says

```
if(i == 4) ... 
... strLine.toLowerCase().contains(searchFor[i].toLowerCase()) ...
```

Any ideas of how I can better implement this functionality?

Thanks,
Jordan

Comment: strLine and the search term have to be converted to be lowercase and then compared. This way you ignore the case.

Comment: Yes I know that much, but I need to figure out a way to toggle that "option" so to speak.

Comment: "toggle" that option with a boolean in the method params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an array of Strings with entries that need to be treated differently (i.e. *case sensitive* and *case insensitive*), I recommend to create an own class for search terms with a `case` setting:

```
public class SearchTerm {
    private final String term;
    private final boolean caseSensitive;

    public SearchTerm(final String term, final boolean caseSensitive) {
        this.term = term;
        this.caseSensitive = caseSensitive;
    }

    public String getTerm() {
        return term;
    }

    public boolean isCaseSensitive() {
        return caseSensitive;
    }
}
```

Then you can use that class to replace the current array:

```
count(SearchTerm[] searchFor, String fileName)
```

And use it in your search method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < searchFor.length; i++) {
    if (searchFor[i].isCaseSensitive()) {
        if (strLine.contains(searchFor[i].getTerm())) {
            counts[i]++;
        }
    }
    else {
        // this line was "borrowed" from Maroun Marouns answer (you can also use different methods to search case insensitive)
        if (Pattern.compile(strLine, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(searchFor[i].getTerm()).find()) { 
            counts[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

That way you avoid a "global" *case sensitive* or *case insensitive* search and you can treat each search term differently.

Comment: I think you have the case sensitivity thing the wrong way round in the for loop but other than that this is a perfect answer and exactly what i was looking for. thank you ever so much :D

Comment: @ColonelSpuds Well, if `searchFor[i].isCaseSensitive()` is `true`, then it uses the case sensitive `contains` method. Mind that you should set the value in `SearchTerm` to `true` if he should search *case sensitive* and to `false` if he should search *case insensitive*.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just add a `boolean ignoreCase` in the method params?

Or you could make an overloaded method.

```
public int[] count(String[] searchFor, String fileName, boolean ignoreCase) {}
```

Comment: It sounds like he want to treat each entry of `searchFor` differently. So a "global" flag won't help him here.

Comment: Very true, I must have misread part of the OP's question. Your answer, with the SearchTerm class is a much better implementation for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Pattern#CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) and implement your own method:

```
private boolean myContains(your_parameters, boolean caseSensitive) {
    if(!caseSensitive)
        return Pattern.compile(strLine, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(searchFor[i]).find();
    return strLine.contains(searchFor[i]);
}
```

Comment: How does regex come in the picture? And why is it compiled as case insensitive, when the parameter `caseSensitive` is true?

Comment: @bali182 Typo, fixed. It's just another way to check it it contains. This trick does that, try it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache `StringUtils.ContainsIgnoreCase()` to the rescue. More on it [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).